# custom user model with slug field

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have a custom user model, and I am adding a slug field to the model. T problem is I don't know how it should be handled in the user manager.

Note: I use signals to create the data for the slug

model.py

```
class UserManager(BaseUserManager):

  def _create_user(self, email, fullname, password, is_staff, is_superuser, **extra_fields):
    if not email:
        raise ValueError('Users must have an email address')
    now = timezone.now()
    email = self.normalize_email(email)
    fullname = fullname
    user = self.model(
        email=email,
        fullname=fullname,
        is_staff=is_staff, 
        is_active=True,
        is_superuser=is_superuser, 
        last_login=now,
        date_joined=now, 
        **extra_fields
    )
    user.set_password(password)
    user.save(using=self._db)
    return user

  def create_user(self, email, fullname, password, **extra_fields):
    return self._create_user(email, fullname, password, False, False, **extra_fields)

  def create_superuser(self, email, fullname, password, **extra_fields):
    user=self._create_user(email, fullname, password, True, True, **extra_fields)
    user.save(using=self._db)
    return user


class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    username = None
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=254, unique=True)
    fullname = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_superuser = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    last_login = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
    date_joined = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=255, unique=True)


    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['fullname']

    objects = UserManager()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email
```

signals.py

```
@receiver(pre_save, sender=settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
def add_slug_to_user(sender, instance, *args, **kwargs):
    if instance and not instance.slug:
        slug = slugify(instance.fullname)
        random_string = generate_user_string()
        instance.slug = slug + "-" + random_string
```

the problem is how do I handle the slug field in the BaseUserManager if I am using signals to get it created, the methods I try out I get errors, like

```
TypeError: create_superuser() missing 1 required positional argument: 'slug'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In user model modify slug model as such:

```
slug = models.SlugField(max_length=255, unique=True, null=True, blank=True)
```

This will make the slug field optional and it will not be required to create a user (like the field last_login).

I suggest that instead of using signals for creating slugs, override models save() method because signals are generally used with relation to other models and usage of signal is highly unnecessary here. So add this method to your custom user model instead:

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    slug = slugify(self.fullname)
    random_string = generate_user_string()
    self.slug = slug + "-" + random_string
    super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```